# Combination of VAL and Transform with visual fox pro to c# conversion

Tags: c#, visual-foxpro

I'm trying to understand the following logic and why the output is what it is. Yes of course, another c# / .net person trying to translate VFP.

I've chopped it down to the bare minimum:

```
a = 19537.7
b = 23810.73
result1 = a-((b/a-1)*a)    
result2 = TRANSFORM(result1,[999.99])
result3 = VAL(result2)
```

- result1: `15264.67000`
- result2: `"***.**"`
- result3: `0.00`

I'm using a VFP library for some of these functions, such as TRANSFORM, but it doesn't do anything. It just spits out the same value I put in but returns it as a string. Not sure what's wrong there.

The value that I get in c# is `15264.670000000000000000000000`.

Okay so digging into the VFP docs, here's the explanation:

1. Truncate decimal places and round the remaining decimal portion of the field.
2. If the value does not fit, store the field contents using scientific notation.
3. If the value still does not fit, replace the field contents with asterisks.

Anyone have a working method they can share for **TRANSFORM()** function? And hopefully **VAL()** as well because the  helper library I'm using tries to convert to an int32 but VFP is certainly not doing that.

Comment: Not sure what you’re asking for? The C# equivalent of these functions?

Comment: @stuartd, Correct... and for the scope of my application I can probably just use some math and produce the same result, but considering this function cannot be found in helper libraries (at least I haven't found it) hopefully this will help others as well.

Comment: Been a very long time since I used VFP but this code _seems_ to be supposed to round a number to two decimal places. But you would use ROUND for that. I think you’re going to have to use the context the actual actual code appears in to translate it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To start with:

```
a = 19537.7
b = 23810.73
result1 = a-((b/a-1)*a)    
result2 = TRANSFORM(result1,[999.99])
result3 = VAL(result2)
```

in VFP is just bad programming, or those lines were never supposed to get a result over 999.99.

What transform() does in VFP is simply to cast any value to a string based on a format along with some formatting symbols. Here TRANSFORM() is simply attempting a string formatting of 5:F2:

```
decimal a = 19537.7M;
decimal b = 23810.73M;
var result1 = a - ((b / a - 1) * a);
Console.WriteLine(result1);
var result2 = $"{result1,5:F2}";
Console.WriteLine(result2);
decimal.TryParse(result2, out decimal result3);
Console.WriteLine(result3);
```

This is normally the equivalant of the VFP code. However, in VFP, you might consider that a bug, if the resulting string length is greater than the format specification than length is obeyed and the value "overflows", and it has a string representation matching format as `"***.**"`. * means the numeric value overflowed the "storage string length".

Val() simply is a conversion from a string to numeric (float). In VFP, since the resulting value is the buggy `"***.**"`, its conversion to numeric results in 0.
In VFP, if a string doesn't represent a numeric, unlike C#, instead of throwing an exception, it is 0. This looks like doing the conversion with .TryParse() where it wouldn't throw an exception but be 0 as well.

Since in C#, "transform" step wouldn't do that buggy and instead return the value without data loss, in C# you get the correct value back with 2 decimals.

IOW, to your chance you were trying to translate a badly coded portion of VFP code.